# Can't solve "FileEditorInput cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm writing a plugin for eclipse (mars), and I'm trying to read the current file that's being edited.
To do so, I need to use FileEditorInput class.
I tried to add org.eclipse.ui.ide to the plugin's dependencies (As I saw it was advised in various forums), but it I can't find it.
I tried importing a jar of org.eclipse.ui.ide to the project, didn't help.

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`org.eclipse.ui.ide` is the correct dependency, it must be listed in your MANIFEST.MF

Open the editor for the MANIFEST.MF of your plugin. Go to the 'Dependencies' tab. On the 'Required Plug-ins' section click 'Add...' and you should be able to add 'org.eclipse.ui.ide'

You must use this method for plug-in dependencies. Do not try just adding to the Java Build Path or including plugin jars directly.

Comment: Yes I tried to do exactly that, but when I click on ADD and insert org.eclipse.ui.ide, it doesn't find it. I can not add it to the required plug-ins.

Comment: What are you using as your Target Platform?

Comment: How do you know which dependency to import? I've copied a snippet of the internet and it seems I'm lacking the dependency that provides JavaUI. What steps do I need to take to figoure out what dependency to import?

Comment: @greg-449 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736233/how-to-determine-which-eclipse-dependencies-to-use